# Microsoft Offline Transliteration API

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, transliteration

For one of my web application(Intranet based), I want to make transliteration from English to some other language.

So is there any Microsoft API available that I can use in my web application.

Don't want to use Google API. It should be Microsoft or any other third party.

Comment: Have you take a look at this? http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/translator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Translator API](http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/translator). Also you may find more resources on the [Bing developer resources](http://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center) page.